# Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: There is already a lease present

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

Am getting the below error with using the event hub binding.

```
  public static  void Run([EventHubTrigger("tlog_eh_policy", Connection = "EventHub_Conn")] EventData[] events, ILogger log, ExecutionContext context)
```

Some of the messages are processed and saved by Azure function and some are skipped. I found the below error in the Azure function live metrics. Any idea on this

Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: There is already a lease present.
   at Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Processor.AzureStorageCheckpointLeaseManager.AcquireLeaseCoreAsync(AzureBlobLease lease)
   at Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Processor.PartitionManager.<>c__DisplayClass12_2.<b__2>d.MoveNext()
Request Information
RequestID:7fa2a7c1-a01e-0046-0b06-b2062d000000
RequestDate:Fri, 13 Dec 2019 22:44:14 GMT
StatusMessage:There is already a lease present.
ErrorCode:LeaseAlreadyPresent
ErrorMessage:There is already a lease present.
RequestId:7fa2a7c1-a01e-0046-0b06-b2062d000000
Time:2019-12-13T22:44:14.1251726Z

Comment: Can you show us the completed code, and are you creating the function in portal or visual studio? For event hub, you're using basic tier or standard tier?

Comment: Hi sam, I just want to check if you have solved this issue?

Comment: Thanks Ivan for checking . Yes the issue is solved.  The event hub connection was  used on more than one active component  was the issue . After removed the event hub connectivity on one of the unused application or component this issue got fixed .

Comment: Hi sam, so glad the issue is solved. And I post an answer, could you please help accept it as answer? so that if any one has the same issue, they can benefit from this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the event hub connection string is used by more than 1 app / active component, there is the possibility cause the issue "There is already a lease present" due to concurrent blob storage usage.

So you can use the connection string just for 1 app / active component to avoid this issue.